# Create React App - (ESLint) Failed to load config "shared-config" to extend from. Referenced from: <PATH> in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, create-react-app, eslint

I have created a react app from the Create React App getting started guide with `--template typescript`.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

I have extended my config to use ESLint.

package.json:

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app", "shared-config"],
    "rules": {
      "additional-rule": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "additional-typescript-only-rule": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/

ESLint works perfectly when running `npm run build` and shows up in Chrome Developer Console but within Visual Studio I get the following error:

> (ESLint) Failed to load config "shared-config" to extend from.
> Referenced from: <package.json PATH>

[image]

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `"shared-config"` is referring to a config that's published and is actually just there for reference, just as there's no such rule as `"additional-rule"` or `"additional-typescript-only-rule"`.

To solve your error message, you can simply remove the entry or replace it with a proper shared config (e.g. `"eslint-config-airbnb"`). Make sure you install any new configs you add, though.

Comment: I have removed it but I 've got a new error `src\components\App.js
  Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'additional-rule' was not found  additional-rule`

Comment: Just to correct the "shared-config": for "eslint-config-airbnb", the config of extends should be: `"extends": ["react-app", "airbnb"]`